# Form with multiples fields_for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

here's my problem. (Rails 4)

I've a purchase and I want to be able to add multiple purchase_items at the same time in one form.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchase_items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchase_items

class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
  params.require(:purchase).permit(:purchase_items => [:item_id, :amount, :comment])


= form_for @purchase do |f|
  %h2 Passer ma commande personnelle
  %ul#ul-services
    - @services.each_with_index do |service_item, index|
      - index.even? ? float="float:left" : float="float:right" 
      %li.list-services{:style => float}
        = f.fields_for @purchase.purchase_items.build, name: 'purchase_items', index: "" do |p|
          = p.hidden_field :item_id, :value => service_item.id
    = f.submit "Commander", :class => "btn btn-success add-to-cart" , :id => "add-to-cart"
```

where @purchase is new purchase

When I submit the form, I always have one purchase_item

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"yAsIoQPO2qEP+BBPA5UOvjUOM9b4Yh6b8bXy4H71P+c=",
"purchase"=>{"purchase_item"=>{"item_id"=>"151",
"amount"=>"0",
"comment"=>""}},
"commit"=>"Commander"}
```

I can't figure out how to get multile purchase_items in the submit result.
I've test multiple things but still stuck on the same problem.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try to add `index` option to the `fields_for` method, `= f.fields_for f.object.purchase_items.build, index: index do |p|...`

Comment: perfect ! that work's, thanks a lot, as extra answer can you explain me what's the difference putting index out there ? 

Still thanks à lot

Answer (score 1):

To use array-like parameters add an `index` option to the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) method:

```
= f.fields_for f.object.purchase_items.build, index: index do |p|
  # some code here
```

I was with the same problem and forget where i found this tricky option.

[image]

Happy coding!

Comment: one last thinks, even if I've all my purchase items now, the hash is "purchase"=>{"purchase_item"=> instead of "purchase"=>{"purchase_items"=>

Comment: you can try an another option `name: 'purchase_items'` in the `fields_for` method. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It doesn't, I keep looking for a solution because I can't pass my purchase_params then `params.require(:purchase).permit(:purchase_items => [:item_id, :amount, :comment])` => `param is missing or the value is empty: purchase`

Comment: it's throw error about the first key `purchase`, please show the full code of the form

Comment: I updated my initial post with the form code which throw the error, doesn't it possible that it think it's empty because it can't see purchase_itemS and see purchase_item

Comment: @Thounder can you also include a part of the log file  with related params?

Comment: @Thounder try this `= f.fields_for :purchase_items, @purchase.purchase_items.build, index: "" do |f|`

Answer (score 0):

```
Started POST "/purchases" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-11 11:01:15 +0200
Processing by PurchasesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yAsIoQPO2qEP+BBPA5UOvjUOM9b4Yh6b8bXy4H71P+c=", "purchase"=>{"type_of"=>"2", "purchase_item"=>[{"item_id"=>"378", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"184", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"188", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"201", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"199", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"185", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"186", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"193", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"182", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"19", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"196", "amount"=>"2", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"195", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"197", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}, {"item_id"=>"191", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""},   {"item_id"=>"190", "amount"=>"0", "comment"=>""}]}, "commit"=>"Commander"}
Unpermitted parameters: purchase_item
```

log clearely show that purchase_item isn't authorize, it's should be the has_many